# Clipboard for copying and pasting files in command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, directory, filenames, command-history

In Bash, suppose I visit a directory, and then another directory. I would like to copy a file from the first directory to the second directory, but without specifying the long pathnames of them. Is it possible?

My temporary solution is to use `/tmp` as a temporary place to store a copy of the file. `cp myfile /tmp` when I am in the first directory, and then `cp /tmp/myfile .` when I am in the second directory. But I may check if the file will overwrite anything in `/tmp`.

Is there something similar to a clipboard for copying and pasting a file?

Comment: You have to type the `cd` command, so you can just `cd -` to go back to the previous directory, up-arrow to recall the `cd` command, and edit the line to be `cp` instead of `cd`.  (ctrl-a(beginning-of-line), alt-d (kill-word), `cp -a`, ctrl-e(end-of-line)).

Comment: With Emacs and `M-x term` you can use Emacs' clipboard.

Comment: You can use Midnight Commander and forget about jumping through the hoops.

Comment: @PålGD People say Emacs' is an operating system... Most have clipboards ;)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Using Bash, I would just visit the directories:

```
$ cd /path/to/source/directory
$ cd /path/to/destination/directory
```

Then, I would use the shortcut `~-`, which points to the previous directory:

```
$ cp -v ~-/file1.txt .
$ cp -v ~-/file2.txt .
$ cp -v ~-/file3.txt .
```

---

If one wants to visit directories in reverse order, then:

```
$ cp -v fileA.txt ~-
$ cp -v fileB.txt ~-
$ cp -v fileC.txt ~-
```

Comment: +1 I'm using Unix/Linux shells for more than 20 years now, and I didnt' know that shortcut.

Comment: Huh, that is a handy shortcut for `"$OLDPWD"`.  Why three separate `cp` commands, though?  `cp -a ~-/file[1-3].txt .`

Comment: Actually,  the three `cp`'s are examples. In the real world, wildcard characters can also be used to simplify the copy task.

Comment: I was going to mention something about `pushd` and parsing `dirs`...but this is far, far better.  I suggest you add the fact that `"$OLDPWD"` is exactly equivalent to `~-` and is more portable (helpful for those not using `bash`.)

Comment: `~+` is likewise a shortcut for `"$PWD"`

Answer (score 11):

If I saw that situation coming as a one-off, I might:

```
a=`pwd`
cd /somewhere/else
cp "$a/myfile" .
```

If there were directories that I found myself copying files out of semi-regularly, I would probably define some mnemonic variables for them in my .profile.

#### Edited to add:

After sleeping on it, I wondered how closely I could get to other GUI / OS behaviors where you select some number of files, "cut" or "copy" them, then "paste" them somewhere else. The best selection mechanism I could come up with was your brain/preferences plus the shell's globbing feature. I'm not very creative with naming, but this is the basic idea (in Bash syntax):

```
function copyfiles {
  _copypastefiles=("$@")
  _copypastesrc="$PWD"
  _copypastemode=copy
}

function cutfiles {
  _copypastefiles=("$@")
  _copypastesrc="$PWD"
  _copypastemode=cut
}

function pastefiles {
  for f in "${_copypastefiles[@]}"
  do
    cp "${_copypastesrc}/$f" .
    if [[ ${_copypastemode} = "cut" ]]
    then
      rm "${_copypastesrc}/$f"
    fi
  done
}
```

To use it, put the code into ~/.bash_profile, then `cd` to the source directory and run either `copyfiles glob*here` or `cutfiles glob*here`. All that happens is that your shell expands the globs and puts those filenames into an array. You then `cd` to the destination directory and run `pastefiles`, which executes a `cp` command for each source file. If you had previously "cut" the files, then pastefiles also removes the source file (or, tries to). This doesn't do any error-checking (of existing files, before potentially clobbering them with the `cp`; or that you have permissions to remove the files during a "cut", or that you can re-access the source directory after you move out of it).

Comment: For your one-off, `$OLDPWD` already exists, which can be shortened to `~-` in bash and zsh.

Answer (score 5):

I think the `~-` is the right answer, but note that bash has a **built-in line editor** that can copy/paste text.

If you are in emacs mode you can recall your `cd` command from the history, and use <kbd>Control-u</kbd> to *kill* the line into the bash "clipboard" called the kill-ring (there are other ways too). You can then *yank* this string into a new command at any time with <kbd>Control-y</kbd>. Obviously, in your example this depends on you having used an absolute directory name in your `cd` command.

You can also use the interesting default key-binding of <kbd>Meta-.</kbd>. This **copies the last word** from the previous command into your current line. If repeated, each time it goes back one command in the history.  So if you do a `cd /x`, then `cd /y` followed by `cd`<kbd>Meta-.</kbd><kbd>Meta-.</kbd> you will have `/x` in your input.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on [the answer from Anderson M. Gomes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268824/138777), Bash allows you to refer to any prior directory in your directory stack by typing `~N` (or `~+N`) where `N` is the position on the dir stack.  For example:

```
# go some places
$ cd /path/to/source/directory
$ pushd /path/to/destination/directory
$ pushd $HOME
$ pushd /tmp

# show the current dir stack
$ dirs -v
0 /tmp
1 ~
2 /path/to/destination/directory
3 /path/to/source/directory
```

Now you can copy a file between two past directories, neither of them the current one, with:

```
cp -v ~3/file1.txt ~2
```

---

To solve the original poster's problem, you would do:

```
$ cd /path/to/source/directory
$ pushd /path/to/destination/directory

# show the current dir stack
$ dirs -v
0 /path/to/destination/directory
1 /path/to/source/directory

# copy
cp -v ~1/file[123].txt .
```

With a large set of files, you could list their names in a manifest file and then do the copy from the source dir:

```
$ cd /path/to/destination/directory
$ pushd /path/to/source/directory

# copy
cp -v $(cat files_to_copy.list) ~1
```

See also: [this section of the Bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion)

---

Similarly, in Tcsh, you can use the `=2` notation (rather than `~2`) to refer to the second dir on your dir stack.

See also: [this section of the Tcsh man page](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Directory_stack_substitution.html)

Answer (score 4):

when you are in the first directory, lets say the source or `src` in short, execute

```
src=${PWD}
```

then `cd` in to second directory and execute:

```
cp -i ${src}/filename .
```

the `-i` option will ask if you want to overwrite, if there is a duplicate file

Comment: Thanks. It is even better without specifying the filename.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on anderson-m-gomes response.
Using Bash, I would just visit the directories:

```
$ cd /path/to/source/directory
$ cd /path/to/destination/directory
```

Then, I would use the variable $OLDPWD, which points to the previous directory:

```
$ cp -v $OLDPWD/file1.txt .
```

If one wants to visit directories in reverse order, then:

```
$ cp -v fileA.txt $OLDPWD/
```

Comment: +1, but you forgot to "quote" your variable expansions.  If `$OLDPWD` contains spaces, this breaks.  Also, I always use `cp -a`.  Also, it's unfortunate that tab-completion is broken on variable expansions.  You can use ctrl-alt-e to shell-expand the current command line, though, after typing the $OLDPWD part.

Comment: `~-` is a shortcut for `$OLDPWD`

Comment: I was just pointing out another variation, since Unix/Linux is full of them.  Funny, that I've been using Linux for >20 years, and I'd never seen ~- before.  Plus, $OLDPWD is easy to remember.

Answer (score 3):

If in bash, I would use [pushd](http://ss64.com/bash/pushd.html) and [popd](http://ss64.com/bash/popd.html). These commands keep a handy FIFO stack of directories for later use. You can consult the stack anytime using [dirs](http://ss64.com/bash/dirs.html).

As such I would do:

```
pushd .
cd /somewhere/else
cp "`popd`/myfile"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`xclip`**:

```
NAME
       xclip - command line interface to X selections (clipboard)

SYNOPSIS
       xclip [OPTION] [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Reads  from standard in, or from one or more files, and makes the data available as an X selection for pasting
       into X applications. Prints current X selection to standard out.
```

Example:

```
$ cd /path/to/dir1
$ xclip-copyfile file1 file2
$ cd /path/to/dir2
$ xclip-pastefile
file1 file2
```

Also visit [xsel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xsel.1x.html).

Comment: That does a `tar | gzip` into / out of the X clipboard.  Kinda clunky compared to `cp`, and doesn't generalize to making symlinks or hardlinks.  (`cp -as` or `cp -al`)

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the `clipboard-files` script here: https://github.com/larspontoppidan/clipboard-files

It provides commands like `ccopy`, `ccut` and `cpaste` that use the desktop environment clipboard and allow intuitive copy / pasting of files:

```
ccopy myfile
cd <second directory>
cpaste
```

As the desktop environment clipboard is used, the copy/pasting will interact with the files put on clipboard in other programs like file managers and IDE's. At least it works on Gnome-like desktops.

Full disclosure, I wrote the script after giving up finding something like it out there...