# cd to previous directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm running CentOS 7, but hoping there is a general Linux way of doing this.

So you can `cd` back and forth between the previous and current directory with this:

```
cd -
```

Is there I way can `cd` back multiple directories? So I keep going back previous directories instead of just the last one?

Does Linux or bash track your navigation history at all?

Comment: you could use bash history by pressing `Ctrl+r`, typing `cd` and repeated `Ctrl+r` to get location you want.. or add `"\e[A": history-search-backward` to `~/.inputrc` and then you could type `cd` followed by repeated `up` arrow to get location you want

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269272/117549

Comment: If the Linux did that, you would have a real bad memory leak. Linux is a kernel it must not do these things. It must only make it possible for processes to do it. (it also does not do the back button in the web-browser). bash is the file browser, so it will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and No.

If you use normal `cd`, it remembers only one previous location (in variable `$OLDPWD`), which is accessible using the mentioned `cd -`.

But you can go around using `pushd path` and `popd`, which keeps stack of previous locations.

Comment: neat so I guess I could alias `cd` to `pushd` and `cd -` to `popd`. Would that screw anything up?

Comment: First try that what does it do and what is in the manual page (in `man bash`). I would not use that for all the `cd`, but it is an option if you need it (you need to know it before you need it :))