# How do I copy a file without pasting immediately from terminal?

Tags: cp

When using the command "cp", I need to know where exactly I want to paste my file. Often, I have to copy a file but without having to paste immediately or sometimes I do not know where I have to paste it. I want to have the option of navigating to the directory where I want to paste the file and then do it. Is there any command that does this?

Basically, I want something like this-

```
cp file.txt
cd ..
cd RandomDirectory
paste
```

This can be done in GUI easily- Ctrl+C the file, navigate to the required directory and then Ctrl+V

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268818/117549

Comment: There are also orthodox file managers (they run in the terminal) that display two panes, and you can navigate to the source directory in one pane and to the target directory in other pane. Ex.: Midnight-Commander, Vifm.

Comment: `xclip` and `xsel` are available for most distros through their standard package management system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this project [clipboard-files](https://github.com/larspontoppidan/clipboard-files). It has the following commands: `ccopy`, `ccut`, `cpaste`, `cshow` and `cclear`.

You can find this example in the `README.md` file:

```
$ ccopy file1.txt file2.jpg
2 item(s) copied to clipboard
$ cshow
Operation: copy
/home/lars/temp/file1.txt
/home/lars/temp/file2.jpg
$ cd folder/
$ cpaste
Copying the following items(s) to current dir:
/home/lars/temp/file1.txt
/home/lars/temp/file2.jpg
$ ccut *
2 item(s) cut to clipboard
$ cd ..
$ cpaste
Moving the following items(s) to current dir:
/home/lars/temp/folder/file1.txt
/home/lars/temp/folder/file2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

One way that would not require installing extra tools would be to copy the file to some easily remembered place, like your home directory or `/tmp`.  Then `cd` to wherever you want to copy the file to and do a `mv` from wherever you copied it to, to the current directory.

Example:

```
$ cp myfile /tmp
$ cd /complicated/path
$ mv /tmp/myfile .
```

Comment: That is what I do now, but seems like a very inconvenient way. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention GUI - another option is to use [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/), a console file manager.

It can also `cd` for you: https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Integration-with-other-programs#changing-directories